# Restrict height of div marked with display:table-cell?

Tags: css

**Problem:**

I need to use `display:table` (in the parent div) and `display:table-cell` (in the contained div) to center some content vertically.  This is working except when the content overflows vertically.  I want to restrict the height so that a scrollbar appears if there's any vertical overflow.

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/110/

(Note that in the output, the div is expanded vertically despite me setting the height to 160px)

**CSS:**

```
side-study-box {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #3D6AA2;
    text-align: center;
    height: 160px !important;
    display: table !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    margin-left: -1px !important;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}

    .side-study-box .side-box-content {
        width: calc(100%);
        height: 160px !important;
        float: right;
        display: table;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .side-study-box .text-content-saved {
        width: 100% !important;
        font-size: 24px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        height: 160px !important;
        max-height: 160px !important;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
        border: 0px !important;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: Try using table-layout: fixed to your table element

Comment: The only thing you can do is to add an extra wrapper, in beteween 'table-cell' and content and set to it a max-height. Table-layout works for width only :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your fiddle updated , with max-height on content wrapper.

```
.side-study-box {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #3D6AA2;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing:1em;
}
.side-box-content {
width: 100%;
  height: ;
   display: table-cell;
}
.text-content-saved {
   max-height:160px;
   overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/6tLAu/

up here   first code was : the box doesn't grow.
down here second does first and centers content if little.

```
.side-study-box {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #3D6AA2;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing:1em;
    height:160px;
}
.side-box-content {
width: 100%;
  height: ;
   display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.text-content-saved {
   max-height:140px;
   overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't keep things centered vertically if there is no overflow :/

Comment: a misunderstanding on my side , did not understood he was talking about inside and not the box itself